# Why is the border width of a button in a React app set to 0.909px by default in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, button

[image]

When I generate a React app using 'npx create-react-app deneme --template typescript' and add a simple button, I see that the button width is set to 0.909px and cannot be changed.

However, when I save the same code as an HTML page and open it in the browser, the button displays with the expected 1px border. I have attached a screenshot. I cannot understand how this is possible.

I can't set it to the default value of 1px even when using the "!important" declaration.

Comment: You seems to have your browser zooming in. Try resetting it to 100%.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again and as your said